# Найти все запятые вне кавычек

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть строка, в которой может быть куча запятых.

Нужно найти те из них, которые находятся вне кавычек и заменить на точки,

```
Было:
текст1,"текст2","текст,3","текст,,,4",текст 5
Должно быть
текст1."текст2"."текст,3"."текст,,,4".текст 5
```

Comment: А кавычки всегда двойные? Или могут быть еще и одинарные (`text, 'text1,text2', "text1, text2"`) А экранирование кавычек в тексте возможно? Т.е. что-то типа `'it\'s my life', "it's your life"` И это не CSV случайно? Если так, то могут быть еще варианты `1;2;"text ""other text""";;3` (разделитель точка с запятой) - т.е. для кавычек внутри текста используется их дублирование. Если учитывать все эти варианты, то конечный ответ может сильно отличаться от текущего

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте `,(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*(?![^"]*"))`

Тест проходит успешно

```java
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class TestRegex {

    @Test
    public void testRegex() throws Exception {
        String src = "текст1,\"текст2\",\"текст,3\",\"текст,,,4\",текст 5";
        String dest = "текст1.\"текст2\".\"текст,3\".\"текст,,,4\".текст 5";

        String regex = ",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*(?![^\"]*\"))";
        String replace = "\\.";

        String result = src.replaceAll(regex, replace);

        assertEquals(dest, result);
    }
}
```